# Continuously changing rectangle python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to make a rectangle in tkinter that changes size continuously with incoming data.I receive the data using a socket and want to display a rectangle and a circle. In every loop, the rectangle changes size and the position of the circle is updated. When the use the code for just the circle, it works fine. But not with the code for the rectangle. I have tried coords and item config. It doesnt work. Could anyone help? Also if this cannot be done with tkinter, can anyone suggest another library?

```
import socket



s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '169.254.1.248'

port=1992
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
cl,address = s.accept()


from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("320x240+0+0")





cnv1 = Canvas(root, width=38, height=240)
cnv1.pack(side="left",fill=BOTH,expand=1)
cnv2 = Canvas(root, width=276, height=240)
cnv2.pack(side="right",fill=BOTH,expand=1)
cnv1.create_rectangle(2, 2, 36, 237, fill="lightblue")
cnv2.create_rectangle(2, 2, 273, 237, fill="lightblue")
cnv2.create_line(2,119.5,273,119.5)
cnv2.create_line(137.5,2,137.5,237)
circ1=cnv1.create_oval(19,118.5,21,120.5, outline="lightblue", fill="",   width=0)
circ2=cnv2.create_oval(134,116,140,122, outline="lightblue", fill="", width=1)
rect=cnv2.create_rectangle(2, 2, 4, 5, fill="", outline="", width =1)

def measurementvolume(z):
    z2 = 2400;z1 =800;x2=1300;x1=400;y2=1500;y1=400
    slope=((x2-x1)/(z2-z1))
    offset = x2-(slope*z2)
    vb=(slope*z) + offset
    slope= ((y2-y1)/(z2-z1))
    offset = y2-(slope*z2)
    hb=(slope*z) + offset
    return [vb,hb]

while True:
    msg=cl.recv(1024)
    strmsg=msg.decode()


    if 'nodata' not in strmsg:

            coords=strmsg.split()
            del strmsg

            cx=(float(coords[0]))/5.51
            cy=(float(coords[1]))/5.51
            cx=cx+117.5
            cy=135.5-cy ##if x axis is not inverted
            cz=float(coords[2])
            cz=-800-cz
            cz=cz/6.78
            boundary=measurementvolume(cz)
            bx=boundary[0]/5.51
            by=boundary[1]/5.51
            upco1=135.5-(abs(by)/2)
            upco2=117.5-(abs(bx)/2)
            upco3=upco1+abs(by)
            upco4=upco2+abs(bx)
            if (abs(by) > cy) and (abs(bx) > cx):
                    cnv2.itemconfig(rect,outline="black",fill="red", width=2)
                    cnv2.coords(rect,upco1,upco2,upco3,upco4)
                    cnv2.itemconfig(circ2,outline="black", fill="black", width=3)
                    cnv2.coords(circ2,cy-3,cx-3,cy+3,cx+3)
                    cnv1.itemconfig(circ1,outline="black", fill="black", width=3)
                    cnv1.coords(circ1,16,cz-3,22,cz+3)


            del cx,cy,cz

    else:

            del strmsg

            cnv2.itemconfig(rect,fill="", outline="lightblue", width =0)
            cnv2.coords(rect,2, 2, 4, 5)
            cnv2.itemconfig(circ2,outline="", fill="", width=0)
            cnv2.coords(circ2,134,116,140,122)
            cnv1.itemconfig(circ1,outline="", fill="", width=0)
            cnv1.coords(circ1,19,118.5,21,120.5)


    root.update()




cl.close()
```